# how to fix boostrap checkbox picker default labels at runtime using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap [checkbox picker plugin](http://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/). It has a `bootstrap-checkbox.js` file which has some default settings values like

```
$.fn.checkboxpicker.defaults = {
    offLabel: 'No',
    onLabel: 'Yes',
    offTitle: false,
    onTitle: true,
    reverse: true
 };
```

I need to set some values on page load and I am trying the following which does not seem to work

```
$(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxpicker();
        $('#renewalStatus').prop('onLabel', 'ON');
        $('#renewalStatus').prop('OffLabel', 'OFF');

    });
```

All I am trying to do here is to replace the `offLabel` text to `OFF` and `onLabel` to `ON`. I can't change the defaults in the script file as I have used the default values in other pages but on this particular page I need slightly different labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

You need to pass your values to the checkboxpicker plugin function.

```js
$(':checkbox').checkboxpicker({onLabel:"ON",offLabel:"OFF"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <script src="http://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/dist/js/bootstrap-checkbox.min.js" ></script>


<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: @Learner - Thanks for the appreciation :)

Comment: Sorry It does not override on the page i.e. the labels are still the same.

Comment: @Learner can you please share your original code of the page?

Comment: the original code is still the same as above in the question. The issue is I can change the default values of the properties in the .js file and it would show but I want to  override in only one page and on that page I have used this script. Also tried `  $(':checkbox').checkboxpicker({ onLabel: "ON", offLabel: "OFF" });` on the page but it does not make any difference

Comment: @Learner you must be missing something. Can you please check if there is any error in the Console (to open console Press F12 key and choose Console tab)

Comment: Strangely ` $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxpicker();
            $(':checkbox').checkboxpicker({ onLabel: "ON", offLabel: "OFF" });` does not work but this does ` $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxpicker({ onLabel: "ON", offLabel: "OFF" });`